# Compile time check while passing values to a function in Kotlin Android

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

I am taking a `JSON` file as input for a class and parsing the values using gson through respective data classes.

I want to call a function that takes a `String` value as an argument.

The string value allowed is decided from the values parsed from `JSON` file. Can I somehow check for that string value passed to the function at compile-time & give an error at compile-time?

Or If I can allow only certain values in the argument for the function based on the values from JSON

**Detailed Explanation of use case:**

I am building a SDK in which a the person using sdk inputs json String. The json is standardised and is parsed in my code.

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "objects": [
        {
            "name": "object1",
            "type": "object1"
         }
      ]
}
```

Here name values and other values may vary based on the input by the developer using it but key remains same. But we need to call a function using the value in objects name parameter.

```
fun testMethod(objectName:String)
```

So developer calls the testMethod as `testMethod(object1)`.

I need to validate `object1` parameter based on json but is there any way possible restricting the test method parameter to `object1` only & give error at compile time if the developer calls `testMethod(obj1)`

Right now I parse JSON & have checks inside the `testMethod()`

Comment: Considering you are parsing the JSON at runtime, your requirements don't sound plausible?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce json is passed at compile-time, it's a kind of SDK that I am making

Comment: If the JSON is known at compile time you can probably make a Android Studio plug-in for it. I highly suspect there is a better solution to your use case though, that does not involve JSON. If you share us more of the specifics of your problem we might be able to help you out with that.

Comment: @Enselic I have edited my question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a JSON validator at compile time, not a Kotlin/Java solution ;)

Comment: I think what you need to write is a custom gradle plugin.  Google and Firebase use this when distributing their processing the json config files.    Haven't tried it myself, but maybe this can you get started: https://proandroiddev.com/gradlepluginandroidsdk-8a2494cbd238

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible to do, but somehow in different way, that you described. First of all, as you already mentioned this behavior could be done easily. For this purpose we have `Objects.requireNotNull()` or `Guava.Preconditions()`. At the same way you can define you checking but this will work on runtime only.

To do in compile time, **you need to create Annotation Preprocessor**. The same, as did in different libraries, and one of them, could be [Lombok](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok), with their `NotNull` and `Nullable`. Android annotation just provide mark and bound for IDE warning, but in their case they adding `NotNull` checking and throw exception for every annotation usage during compile time.

It's not an easy way, but it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

No, it's impossible check it in compiler time. It's string handling, as numeric calculation.

In my app, I convert  string to JSON and JSON to string, passing class descriptor. My aim is record JSON string in a text file to load in SQLite database. This code I've run in my desktop computer not in *Android*.

```
data class calcDescr (  
   ...
)
val calc = CalcDescr(...)

 //    toJson:  internal Kotlin data to JSON
val content = Gson().toJson(calc)   

  //==================
  // Testing validity
  // ================

 //    fromJson: JSON to internal Kotlin data. 
 // It needs pass the class descriptor. Uses *Java* token, but it's *Kotlin*
var testModel = Gson().fromJson(content, CalcDescr::class.java) 
 //    toJson:  internal Kotlin data to JSON again
var contentAgain = Gson().toJson(testModel)
//    shoul be equal!
if (content == contentAgain)  println("***ok***")
```

In my file, I write the variable `content` in a file